# Add node in existing xml file with c++

Tags: c++, xml, file, addition, xerces

I am trying to add nodes into an existing xml file. 
I am programming with C++ using xerces
So either I would load an existing xml file and then add some nodes and save the xml file again. Or I would just add a node to the bottom of the xml file. (inside the tags).

Since now, I am creating my xml files like this:

```
XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize();
DOMImplementation * pImp = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(XMLString::transcode( "core" ) );
xercesc::DOMDocument * pDoc = pImp->createDocument(0,XMLString::transcode("myName"),0 );
DOMElement * pRoot = pDoc->getDocumentElement();

DOMElement * pNode = mkElement( pDoc, "Node" );
setAttribute(pNode, "id",  0 );
setAttribute(pNode, "age", 12);
pRoot->appendChild(pNode);

doXMLOutput( pDoc, "myFile.xml" );
pDoc->release();
XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
```

How can I do something like

```
document  = load("filename.xml")
document.appendChild(myNode)
save(document, "filename.xml")
```

or

```
addNode("filename.xml, myNode)
```

Thank you very much!